# Conjugacy in metaplectic groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, topological-groups

Let $F$ be a non-Archimedean local field (characteristic 0) and $G=GL(2,F)$. Let $\tilde{G}$ be "the" metaplectic double cover of $G$ (defined using an explicit cocycle as in Gelbart's book (Weil's representation and the spectrum of the metaplectic group)). Take $g_{1}, g_{2} \in \tilde{G}$. Suppose we know that their projections $p(g_{1}), p(g_{2})$ to $G$ are conjugate in $G$. Under what conditions can we say that $g_{1}$ is conjugate to $g_{2}$ in $\tilde{G}$. Can we approach the problem of conjugacy in $\tilde{G}$ using just information on $G$?

Comment: Since the projection map is not injective, you can take any nonidentity element in the kernel to see that the answer to your first question is no.